# OpenDKIM permission denied

Tags: centos, permissions, selinux, opendkim

I have installed opendkim on CentOS 6 and set the `TemporaryDirectory` to `/var/tmp` in the `opendkim.conf` configuration file. After restarting the service and trying to send an email I get an error in the postfix log that reads

```
opendkim[27392]: F2C3E20509: dkim_eoh(): resource unavailable: can't create temporary file at /var/tmp/dkim.F2C3E20509.FiOvYB: Permission denied
```

So, I looked into the permissions of the tmp folder (`ls -l /var/`) and they are

```
drwxrwxrwt.  2 root root 4096 Nov 23 20:42 tmp
```

As I understand this, everbody should be able to write into the `/var/tmp` folder. Why is a `Permission denied` error message returned?

Comment: When I change the TemporaryDirectory to just `/tmp` I get the same error message (only with `/tmp` as the path)

Comment: It's an SELinux error. Check your `/var/log/audit/audit.log`. _"type=AVC msg=audit(1483830362.695:363445): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=23193 comm="opendkim" name="tmp" dev=xvde ino=9109 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:dki
m_milter_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0 tclass=dir"_ Sorry I don't know how to fix it yet.

Comment: `# ls -dZ /var/tmp` yields `drwxrwxrwt. root root system_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0       /var/tmp`

Answer (score 1):

- The Updated answer *

Go to **/etc/opendkim.conf** and change this line:

```
TemporaryDirectory /var/tmp
```

to:

```
TemporaryDirectory /var/run/opendkim
```

And restart your mail services (for example

```
# service opendkim restart
# chkconfig opendkim on
# service postfix restart
```

Comment: That totally didn't work.

Comment: Updated the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, this is caused by a missing SELinux policy. You can get the error detailing the missing permissions from the audit log, and use that to generate an SELinux module package with:

```
grep opendkim /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M opendkim
```

The -M option designates the name of the module package, you can name it something else if you like.
That command will generate two files: opendkim.pp, which is the actual selinux module package, and opendkim.te, a text file showing you which policies the module package contains.

If the policies look good, then import the module package with:

```
semodule -i opendkim.pp
```

Comment: That policy says it can write to root directories. That seems a little too permissive! Is there another way that is more specific? `#!!!! The source type 'dkim_milter_t' can write to a 'dir' of the following types:
# dkim_milter_data_t, cluster_var_lib_t, cluster_var_run_t, root_t, cluster_conf_t`

Comment: Strange, I imported the module and it _still_ doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

The question already had a solution [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/824871/how-do-i-modify-selinux-to-allow-opendkim-to-write-to-var-tmp)

*There is no need to allow OpenDKIM to write to any other directories. Just write to the default temporary directory, /var/run/opendkim, which should already exist and have the correct SELinux context to allow it to be written to.*

(And [here](http://lists.elandsys.com/archive/opendkim/users/2016/03/3675.html) is a solution to **avoid** this problem in SELinux way.)

So.    Very old thread that defies resolution. And about few days ago, i find this thread since ive got a same problem and solved by use Dedgar's solution.

And you can try below what if you really want to set `Temporary` to `/var/tmp`

log looks like:

```
opendkim[46233]: E9A563F480: dkim_eoh(): resource unavailable: can't create temporary file at /var/tmp/dkim.E9A563F480.IjgWhi: Permission denied
```

And as Chloe said. it's an SELinux error because`everbody should be able to write into the /var/tmp folder`

Check log file
`# grep opendkim /var/log/audit/audit.log`
Got:

```
...
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1484968513.231:1415886): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=7fc21e6e4910 a1=c2 a2=180 a3=0 items=0 ppid=46231 pid=14906 auid=500 uid=497 gid=497 euid=497 suid=497 fsuid=497 egid=497 sgid=497 fsgid=497 tty=(none) ses=3274 comm="opendkim" exe=2F7573722F7362696E2F6F70656E646B696D202864656C6574656429 subj=unconfined_u:system_r:dkim_milter_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1484968573.318:1415887): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=14916 comm="opendkim" name="tmp" dev=dm-0 ino=129564 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:dkim_milter_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0 tclass=dir
...
```

As Dedgar said, it seems like opendkim missing a policy which can create file from `tmp` file. 
So first, check dir type

```
# ll -Zd /var/tmp/
drwxrwxrwt. root root system_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0       /var/tmp/
```

then check if `opendkim` have permission to access `/var/tmp`

```
# ll -Z /usr/sbin/opendkim 
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:dkim_milter_exec_t:s0 /usr/sbin/opendkim
# sesearch -A -s dkim_milter_t| grep tmp_t
```

Output may looks like:

...
   allow daemon puppet_tmp_t : file { ioctl read write getattr lock append } ; 
   allow dkim_milter_t tmp_t : file { write create unlink open } ; 
   allow dkim_milter_t tmp_t : dir { write add_name remove_name } ; 
   allow domain tmp_t : dir { getattr search open } ; 
   ...

Notice of the line

```
allow dkim_milter_t tmp_t : file { write create unlink open } ; 
allow dkim_milter_t tmp_t : dir { write add_name remove_name } ;
```

It almost tell use `dkim_milter_t` have permission to access directories with type `tmp_t` like `/var/tmp`,

But most case we don't have this line output or this conf doesn't work at all or other case...

So, we need to add a policy that give permission to policy `dkim_milter_t` which `opendkim` use to access file or dirs have `type` `tmp_t`.
And most simple way is using [audit2allow](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/sec-sel-building-policy-module.html) like Dedgar put:

```
grep opendkim /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M opendkim
semodule -i opendkim.pp
```

it will generate a SELinux policy to do things before. 
But not surely know it won't work in Chloe's case.
Put my opendkim.te :

```
module opendkim 1.0;

require {
        type tmp_t;
        type dkim_milter_t;
        class dir { write remove_name add_name };
        class file { write create unlink open };
}
allow dkim_milter_t tmp_t:dir { write remove_name add_name };
allow dkim_milter_t tmp_t:file { write create unlink open };
```

And what if you need regenerate file(opendkim.pp for this) manually.

```
checkmodule -M -m -o opendkim.mod opendkim.te
semodule_package -o opendkim.pp -m opendkim.mod
```

And `semodule -i opendkim.pp` for what you need.