# How do I modify SELinux to allow OpenDKIM to write to /var/tmp?

Tags: centos, selinux, opendkim

I tried this answer (https://serverfault.com/a/744756/123651) but it still gives an error.

> Jan  7 23:56:33 ip-172-31-15-65 opendkim[24223]: AF15521407: dkim_eoh(): resource unavailable: can't create temporary file at /var/tmp/dkim.AF15521407.ennuJK: Permission denied

Here are some of the `audit.log`

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1483827348.024:363280): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=22334 comm="opendkim" name="tmp" dev=xvde ino=40961 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:dkim_milter_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1483827348.024:363280): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=7f7eecd1f910 a1=c2 a2=180 a3=0 items=0 ppid=22035 pid=22334 auid=0 uid=495 gid=495 euid=495 suid=495 fsuid=495 egid=495 sgid=495 fsgid=495 tty=(none) ses=4038 comm="opendkim" exe="/usr/sbin/opendkim" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:dkim_milter_t:s0 key=(null)
```

---

```
# cat opendkim.te

module opendkim 1.0;

require {
        type tmp_t;
        type dkim_milter_t;
        class dir write;
}

#============= dkim_milter_t ==============
#!!!! The source type 'dkim_milter_t' can write to a 'dir' of the following types:
# dkim_milter_data_t, cluster_var_lib_t, cluster_var_run_t, root_t, cluster_conf_t

allow dkim_milter_t tmp_t:dir write;

# semodule -i opendkim.pp

# ls -ldZ /var/tmp
drwxrwxrwt. root root system_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0       /var/tmp

# service opendkim restart
Stopping OpenDKIM Milter:                                  [  OK  ]
Starting OpenDKIM Milter:                                  [  OK  ]
```

I don't know what else to try.

Reference: I used this guide: https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-and-integrate-opendkim-with-postfix-on-a-centos-6-vps/

CentOS release 6.8 (Final)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to allow OpenDKIM to write to any other directories. Just write to the default temporary directory, `/var/run/opendkim`, which should already exist and have the correct SELinux context to allow it to be written to.

Comment: Interesting, that dir does exist, however it wasn't used in the guide mentioned for the `TemporaryDirectory`.

Comment: @Chloe There are all sorts of bad guides out there. In fact, most of them have errors or problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think what `Michael Hampton♦` said is the best solution.

But what if you really need set `Temporary` to `/var/tmp`

Then you can try below.

1. We need to modify the policy what `dkim_milter_t` had originally.
   so, create a `.te` file (example `opendkim.te` below)
2. Let `dkim_milter_t` have permission to access `tmp_t` what type that dir `/var/tmp/` is.

   `# ll -Zd /var/tmp/
   drwxrwxrwt. root root system_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0       /var/tmp/`

file may looks like below

```
module opendkim 1.0;

require {
        type tmp_t;
        type dkim_milter_t;
        class dir { write remove_name add_name };
        class file { write create unlink open };
}
allow dkim_milter_t tmp_t:dir { write remove_name add_name };
allow dkim_milter_t tmp_t:file { write create unlink open };
```

Of course you can change it suitable. but i think it is what you need least.
It actually give the permission to `dkim_milter_t` to write remove create open file from `/var/tmp/`

3. Regenerate opendkim.pp manually

   `checkmodule -M -m -o opendkim.mod opendkim.te`

   `semodule_package -o opendkim.pp -m opendkim.mod`
4. Enable change

   `semodule -i opendkim.pp`

Maybe you need further more help [here](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/sec-sel-building-policy-module.html).
And for [man](https://linux.die.net/man/8/checkmodule).

Answer (score -3):

```
# setenforce permissive
# service opendkim restart
... send mail to myself ...
# setenforce enforcing
# grep opendkim /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M opendkim
# cat opendkim.te

module opendkim 1.0;

require {
        type tmp_t;
        type dkim_milter_t;
        type sysctl_vm_t;
        class dir { write remove_name search add_name };
        class file { write read create unlink open };
}

#============= dkim_milter_t ==============
allow dkim_milter_t sysctl_vm_t:dir search;
allow dkim_milter_t sysctl_vm_t:file read;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow dkim_milter_t tmp_t:dir write;
allow dkim_milter_t tmp_t:dir { remove_name add_name };
#!!!! The source type 'dkim_milter_t' can write to a 'file' of the following types:
# dkim_milter_data_t, cluster_var_lib_t, cluster_var_run_t, root_t, cluster_conf_t

allow dkim_milter_t tmp_t:file { write create unlink open };
```

---

```
# semodule -i opendkim.pp
```

Comment: Please expand on your solution and explain it, thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: @Chloe Did you intend to post this an an answer? I don't think so.